# How can I use toString() from Author class in another class constructor Book()?

Tags: java, string, class, object, parameters

I want to use Authors full name(toString()) from Author class in another Book() class where I added a constructor but I could not figure out how can I pass it from the Author() class.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Author firstAuthor = new Author("Alex", "Ahamed");
        System.out.println(firstAuthor.toString());
        Author secondAuthor = new Author("Ben", "Wattson");
        System.out.println(secondAuthor.toString());
    }

    public static class Author {

        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public Author(String fName, String sName) {
            this.firstName = fName;
            this.lastName = sName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName = fName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String sName) {
            lastName = sName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public String toString() {
            String str;
            str = firstName + " " + lastName;
            return str;
        }
    }

    public static class Book {
        private String title;
        private String author;
        private double price;
        
        public Book(String title, Author name, double price){
            this.title = title;
            this.author = name;
            this.price = price;
        }
    }

}
```

In this.author line, I get the error : Incompatible types: Author cannot be converted to String.

Comment: `name.toString()` in `public Book(String title, Author name, double price)` or `author.toString()` if I'm not missing something

Comment: just call toString explicitly? `this.author = name.toString()`, but toString isn't supposed to be used this way, I'd rather expose another field for Author, `fullName` or so

Comment: Thanks it works. But in my Homework paper I was asked to use Author class in the Book() class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the method `toString()` inside the `this.author` declaration:

```
public Book(String title, Author name, double price){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = name.toString();
    this.price = price;
}
```

But, as said in the comments, is better create a field with the full name concatenated.
Like this:

```
 public static class Author {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String fullName;

    public Author(String fName, String sName) {
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = sName;
        this.fullName = fName + " " + sName;
    }

   ...

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But in my Homework paper I was asked to use Author class in the Book() class constructor.

Comment: But you are using. The `name` declared in the parameters of Book() constructor, is of the type Author, with `name.toString()`, you are reffering to the method `toString()` of your Author class, returning a concatenated full name String. I reccomend changing the `name` for something like `author`, it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should declare `author` of type, `Author`.
2. Then, you can simply use `author` in `Book#toString`.

**Code:**

```
class Book {
    private String title;
    private Author author;
    private double price;

    public Book(String title, Author author, double price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [title=" + title + ", author=" + author + ", price=" + price + "]";
    }
}
```

With change,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Author firstAuthor = new Author("Alex", "Ahamed");
    Author secondAuthor = new Author("Ben", "Wattson");
    Book book1 = new Book("Hello World", firstAuthor, 10);
    Book book2 = new Book("Hello Stackoverflow", secondAuthor, 15);
    System.out.println(book1);
    System.out.println(book2);
}
```

will output

```
Book [title=Hello World, author=Alex Ahamed, price=10.0]
Book [title=Hello Stackoverflow, author=Ben Wattson, price=15.0]
```

Answer (score -1):

super() method is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Can you please explain further how this would be helpful? There is no indication of subclasses in the problem, and it is not clear how `super()` would help even if there were.

Comment: I don't think so